# How to make Jinja2 convert all UndefinedError exceptions to blank strings?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

A lot of the models in my code have relations that can be None. Many times, this requires checks for `None` before accessing the data:

```
{% if foo.bar %}
   {{ foo.bar.baz }}
{% endif %}
```

If I don't add that check, the page breaks completely with an UndefinedError. Is there any way I can fail silently for UndefinedErrors in Jinja2 when run from a Flask app?

Answer (score 8):

Simply create a subclass of [`jinja2.Undefined`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.Undefined) that returns itself on attribute access and set it as the Undefined type for your environment by overriding the [`create_jinja_environment`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.create_jinja_environment) method:

```
from flask import Flask
from jinja2 import Undefined
from werkzeug.datastructures import ImmutableDict

class MalleableUndefined(Undefined):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self


class CustomFlask(Flask):
    def create_jinja_environment(self):
        self.jinja_options = ImmutableDict(undefined=MalleableUndefined, **self.jinja_options)
        return super(CustomFlask, self).create_jinja_environment()
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something but how do I apply this undefined property to my {{ variable }} ?

Comment: @chishaku - simply create your app using the `CustomFlask` sub-class, rather than the normal `Flask` class.